# Is $f(\delta)=\int_{\Omega_\delta\setminus\Omega_{2\delta}}dx$ differentiable at the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\delta\geq0$ and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ a bounded Lipschitz domain (or if necessary, we can assume $\Omega$ is $C^1$) with $N\geq 2$. Define $$\Omega_\delta=\{x\in\Omega:\ \operatorname{d}(x,\partial\Omega)>\delta\}$$

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$f(\delta)=\int_{\Omega_\delta\setminus\Omega_{2\delta}}dx$$

where $dx$ stands for Lebesgue measure. Extend $f$ to a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ in such way that $g$ is even.

My question is: Is $g$ differentiable in the origin?

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Are you making any particular regularity assumptions about $\Omega$? It seems like $|\Omega_\delta \setminus \Omega_{2\delta}|/\delta$ will (very roughly) measure the perimeter of $\Omega$.

Comment: Also, $g$ can be computed exactly when $\Omega$ is a ball, in which case $g'(0)$ exists but is nonzero.

Comment: Yes @UmbertoP., $\Omega$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Yes @UmbertoP. you rigt about the ball, in fact I had alread calculated this example, but now I see that my previous calculation was wrong.

Comment: For fractal boundaries, this limit need not exist, it can oscillate.  (A paper of Falconer, I believe.)  But of course Lipschitz domains are much nicer.